# In Scala cats 2.x, how to create a generic zero functor (given its type class)?

Tags: scala, functor, scala-cats

I'm looking for a method to initialise a zero functor `z: F[_]`, given the type class `Functor[F[_]]`. The zero functor should ensure that any other function compose with it yields a fixed point. I've tried the following code:

```
import cats.Functor
import cats.syntax.functor._
import cats.instances.option._
import cats.instances.list._

def zeroFunctor[F[_]: Functor]: F[Nothing] = {
  val functorInstance = implicitly[Functor[F]]
  functorInstance.map(functorInstance.empty)(_ => ??? : Nothing)
}

val optZero = zeroFunctor[Option]  // None
val listZero = zeroFunctor[List]  // Nil
```

But it failed with the following information:

```
[Error] /home/peng/git/spookystuff/parent/core/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/utils/SpookyViews_Imp0.scala:45:41: value empty is not a member of cats.Functor[F]
```

SO what is the proper way to create it?

Comment: That sounds like `MonoidK.empty` rather than `Functor`, I don't think `Functor` is capable of representing an empty value.

Comment: Because `Functor` is essentially a mapping between two categories which maps every element of category `A` to some element in category `B`. Nothing more.

Comment: I agree, but in math definition, should a functor already be a monoid? function composition has associativity, and there is always an ID functor

Comment: BTW, in cats, this doesn't work: implicit[Monoid[Seq[Int]]], this does: implicit[Monad[Seq]]

Comment: @tribbloid what was suggested was MonoidK rather than Monoid. It's a slightly different thing.

Comment: Ah, I see, almost forgot that Scala is a predicative language :)
There should be a summoning rule from MonoidK to Monoid

Comment: _"The zero functor should ensure that any other function compose with it yields a fixed point."_ - Can you please give any kind of reference about what you mean by "zero functor"; As it is, the question does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: 1. Not every functor is a function. 2. Fixed-point of a function is slightly different thing than a neutral element/identity. 3. What do you mean by "summoning rule from a MonoidK to Monoid"? If you had `List[Int]`: `MonoidK[List]`'s empty is `Nil`. `Monoid[Int]`'s empty could be 0 (+) or 1 (*). What your "summoning from MonoidK to Monoid" should yield? `Nil`? `List(1)`? `List(0)`? 4. Your examples look like something like [`EmptyK`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/main/alleycats-core/src/main/scala/alleycats/EmptyK.scala) from alleycats if you don't want a whole `MonoidK`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin sorry you are right. It is called `absorbing functor` or `absorbing element`, such an esoteric word that only ChatGPT would know

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok That's interesting: 3. I eventually found a function `MonoidK.algebra` that yield a `Monoid`, maybe this should be an implicit? IMHO it is impossible to summon Monoid without knowing the operator, List itself is an operator, but Int is not.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok 2. Based on `.algebra[T]` impl and this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644478/the-definition-of-functor-is-a-functor-a-function. Functor is indeed not a function, but `Functor.algebra[T]` should be (both input and output are types/small categories). Therefore, I don't see a problem declaring it a `MonoidK`

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok 2. Yeah you are both right, I didn't know the right terminology

Comment: @tribbloid you are referring to 1 options that I listed: you can turn `MonoidK[F]` into `Monoid[F[A]]`: you replace `empty: [A] => F[A]` and `combine: [A] => (F[A], F[A]) => F[A]` (using Scala 3 sytnax) with fixing `A` and returning `empty: F[A]` and `combine: `(F[A], F[A]) => F[A]`. I am not sure if it doesn't happen because you haven't done `import cats.implicits.*` or is it intentional when you'd like to separate `MonoidK` from `Monoid` (since they operate on different kinds). I would assume the latter - it's a difference whether you combine "wrapper" (F, regardless of A) or inner type (A).

Comment: in Scala 2.13 (sorry still need to stick to Spark), `import cats.implicits.all._` is still not enough.

I'll try it in Scala 3 shortly, thanks a lot!